# laravel 5 get data from 3 tables with group by

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables schools, classes, attendances which are

```
schools
public function classes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Classes');
}

classes
public function school() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\School');
}
public function attendances() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attendance');
}

attendances
public function classes() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Classes');
}
```

Now I want to get data of attendances group by date which consist of classes for each school, like following

```
date1{
     total attendance: totalNumber,
     classes{
         class1{},
         class2{},
     }
},
date2{
....
}
```

Comment: you want classes grouped by date right?

Comment: yes.. date from attendance table